# why registration password only accepts @ symbol?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

```js
private Boolean validatePass() {
        String val = pass.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
        String passwordVal = "^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,}$";

        if (val.isEmpty()) {
            pass.setError("*Required");
            return false;
        } else if (!val.matches(passwordVal)) {
            pass.setError("Invalid Password");
            return false;
        } else {
            pass.setError(null);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

I used this code for password Validation, what's wrong with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per what your regex code is it should satisfy for all the symbols mentioned there #,?,!,@,$,%,^,&,*,- it will fail if you use symbols other than these like _,+,~,`